# Getting a server certificate without estabilishing an SSL\TLS connection

Tags: certificate

Is there a way to get the certificate of an specific HTTPS URL without estabilishing an SSL/TLS connection?

The case is we are behind a proxy and this proxy does an "SSL inspection", which is basically a man-in-the-middle, presenting its own certificates do the end user while it deals with the server certificate on the other side.

Although the proxy does check the certificate, sometimes it's needed to manually check the server certificate and we need to do that behind the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not rely on the proxy to do all this for you? That's going to do all the hard work. You could establish a tunnel to a particular URL if your only inspecting the certificate of one site and keep the connection open if you're worries about opening lots of connections.

What is the reason for the inspection of the SSL certificate and how come you don't want to create a new connection?

Comment: The reason for checking the certificate information is technical support, cetaily we could whitelist the area (IPs, users, etc) but we would like not to have an exception since we rely on SSL inspection to implement certain policies. The reason for not creating the connection is that the proxy will intercept it and provide its own certificate.

Comment: Aah OK, I think I understand now. Is it possible to have another machine download the certificate for you and pass it to you? One that doesn't sit behind the proxy?

Comment: We contemplated that as well as web based tools like http://www.fixyourip.com/ but the question remains.